# The text continues on the next line in the text box when there is no space between words. CSS problem

Tags: css

I am currently building a typing test, when I call a function named randomParagraph() and it creates a new paragraph, the text that it appears it keeps going even though there is no space between the text.
[This is how the quote looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZmJR.png)

I currently tried this on css

```
.quote p{
  background-color: #cbda4649;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: black 5px 8px 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
  word-wrap: normal break-word initial inherit;
  white-space: initial;
}

.quote p span{
  word-break: break-all;

}

.quote p span.correct {
  color: rgb(16, 106, 16);
}

.quote p span.incorrect {
  color: rgb(125, 41, 41);
  background-color: rgb(247, 101, 101);
  outline: 1px solid  rgb(83, 11, 11);
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
}

/* quote p span.current, is for the blinking caret before the text when the class is current*/
.quote p span.current {
  color: black;
  
}

.quote p span.current:before {
  content: "";
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute; 
  background-color: black;
  animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <title> Typing Test </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="split left">
                <div class="beforetext">
                    <div class="quote"> 
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
            <div class="split right">
                <div class="header">
                    <p> Online Typing Test</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="result-details">
                    <li class="timer">
                        <p class="curr_time">Time Limit</p>
                        <span id="stats" class="timeLeft">60<span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="errors">
                        <p class="curr_errors">Errors</p>
                        <span id="stats" class="statsErrors">0<span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="accuracy">
                        <p class="curr_accuracy">Acuraccy:</p>
                        <span id="stats" class="statsAccuracy">0%<span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cpm">
                        <p class="curr_cpm">CPM</p>
                        <span id="stats" class="statsCPM">0<span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="wpm">
                        <p class="curr_wpm">Wdpm:</p>
                        <span id="stats" class="statsWPM">0<span>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="buttons"> 
                    <li>
                        <button class="button-inside" onclick="reloadStats()">Try Again</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>   
                        <select id="select-time" class="button-inside" value="time-selection" onchange="reloadStats()" onchange="selectTime()" >
                            <option value="long-time">60s</option>
                            <option value="short-time">15s</option>
                            <option value="medium-time">30s</option>
                          </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <select id="select-language" class="button-inside" value="language-selection" onchange=selectLanguage() onchange="randomParagraph()" onchange="reloadStats()">
                            <option value="english">English</option> 
                            <option value="spanish">Español</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>



                <textarea 
                    autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" autofocus=""
                    id="myTextarea"
                    class="input_area"
                    placeholder="Start typing here..."></textarea>"
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/paragraphs.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So here is the HTML where I split the screen in two halves and then I have a quote, where the error is being produced. In the quote it looks like the photo above. Moreover there is a textbox where the user can start typing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't add the generated HTML code, it's not clear *which* element contains the text, but `word-break` needs `normal` as its value (which is the default) for the element that contains the text, to avoid the situation you describe.

Comment: I already added the HTML code as well. Thanks for the clarification of what I needed.